# MYSQL select MIN distance beetween latitude and Longitude

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains column called func_id , latitude and longitude. Im trying to get the min distance row and return the func_id by a function.

I tried:

```
 function Get_Min_func_id($lat, $long){
        $query = mysql_query("
 select func_id,
   MIN( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) 
          * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
          * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('$long') ) 
          + sin( radians('$lat') ) 
          * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )  AS distance 
from entregas 
");

  return @mysql_result($query, 0, 'func_id');
  }
```

But its not working fine. It is returning only the same func_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query that you want:

```
 select func_id,
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) 
          * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
          * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('$long') ) 
          + sin( radians('$lat') ) 
          * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )  AS distance 
 from entregas
 order by distance asc
 limit 1;
```

Your query will return the minimum distance, but an arbitrary value for `func_id`.  As a general rule, you should always have the same columns in a `group by` as in the `select`, unless you are using aggregation functions.  In this case, you have an aggregation query with no `group by`, so there should be no additional columns.